# 2008 Windows Server R2 changes Domain network to Public Network Upon reboot

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-workstation

I have a server that we use for a ghost imaging server for a training lab enviroment. Each lab is on its own VLAN. There are 10 VLANs. The server has DNS, Ghost 2.5.1, and VMware Workstaation 6.5 installed. Multiple VLANs are set by Broadcom NetXtreme II BCAS software. Each lab is 10.10.1.X/24, 10.10.2.X/24, etc., and is listed as TEAM1_ classroom1, etc. There is also an Admin VLAN that connects to a corporate VPN via a firewall/router appliance.

With VMware installed, upon reboot, I lose connection to the corporate domain network. The only way to regain access is to switch the Team1_Admin to get address via DHCP. It will get a 169.254.x.x address. not until reboot will it get the proper one from the firewall/DHCP. Then it will be on the domain network. Then I can hard code the address to what it needs to be. But, upon next reboot, it lost connection again to the domain network. The DNS is set to a server located at corporate.

I have tried to correct the issue with VMware Workstation changing all networks to public by disabling the VMware network adapters and also changing the registry, adding the *NdisDeviceType for each adapter. With VMware uninstalled I can reboot with my hard coded address for Team1_admin and not lose connection. (We use VMware workstation for when we have to image labs with Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the machine was having problems with DNS binding to all VLANS. Went into DNS and allowed DNS to only respond to DNS entries on one VLAN, the, admin one.